# Service Auth0 with front vue js and back node js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, auth0

I'm working with service auth0, I implement on my back the router and services, like:

```
import Router from "express-promise-router";
import authenticationController from "./controller/authentication.controller";
import { validateAccessToken } from "../../auth0/middleware/auth0.middleware";
const authenticationRouter = Router();

authenticationRouter.get(
  "/protected",
  validateAccessToken,
  authenticationController.protected
);

authenticationRouter.get(
  "/admin",
  validateAccessToken,
  authenticationController.admin
);

authenticationRouter.get(
  "/public",
  authenticationController.public
);

export default authenticationRouter;
```

and the middleware, I implemented:

```
const {
  auth,
  claimCheck,
  InsufficientScopeError,
} = require("express-oauth2-jwt-bearer");
import { env } from "../../utils/enviroment";

export const validateAccessToken = auth({
  audience: env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
  issuerBaseURL: `https://${env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}` 
})
```

and in my front:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

  import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-vue";

  const { loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();

  useHead({
    title: 'Login',
  })


  //default redirect to Universal Login of Auth0
  loginWithRedirect({
    appState: {
      target: "/callback",
    },
    authorizationParams: {
      prompt: "login",
    },
  })

</script>

<template>
</template>
```

and on my callback page:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

  import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-vue";
  import { useDarkmode } from '/@src/stores/darkmode'
  import { useUserSession } from '/@src/stores/userSession'
  import { useNotyf } from '/@src/composable/useNotyf'
  import { checkUserLogged } from '/@src/services/checkUser.service'

  const isLoading = ref(false)
  const darkmode = useDarkmode()
  const router = useRouter()
  const route = useRoute()
  const notyf = useNotyf()
  const userSession = useUserSession()
  const { error, isAuthenticated, user, getAccessTokenSilently, logout  } = useAuth0()

  useHead({
    title: 'Index',
  })

  const init = async () => {
    try{
      if(isAuthenticated.value){  

        try {
          const accessToken = await getAccessTokenSilently();
          const userlogged = {
            //@ts-ignore
            email: user._rawValue.email,
            //@ts-ignore
            nickname: user._rawValue.nickname
          }

          //@ts-ignore
          const { data, error } = await checkUserLogged(accessToken, userlogged);

          if(data.authorize){ 
            userSession.setToken( accessToken );
            notyf.dismissAll();
            //@ts-ignore
            notyf.success(`Welcome back, ${user._rawValue.nickname}`);
            router.push('/app')
          }else{
            await logout({});
            router.push('/error')           
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("Try catch: ", error);
          router.push('/error')
        }
      }else{ 
        router.push('/error')
      }
    } catch (error) {
    //  console.error("Error during authentication:", error);
      router.push('/');
    }
  }

  init();

</script>

<template>
  <LandingLayout theme="light">
  </LandingLayout>
</template>
```

each time that I tried to access through universal login, I need to check the token, and then check other filter late, so, currently I'm getting the issue "401 unauthorized" and message "bad credencials".

So, very carefully, I was checking the enviroment, specifically in this part on my back:

```
export const validateAccessToken = auth({
  audience: env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
  issuerBaseURL: `https://${env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}` 
})
```

I use `console.log()` to `env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE` and `env.AUTH0_DOMAIN` and these are correct.

so what' wrong?? I don't know what to do.

I'm using template vuero of vue js 3.